# Loading a multipoint shapefile in R

Tags: vector, r, ogr, multipart

This issue has only been raised in the community once, [two years ago](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2011-July/012423.html), to the best of my knowledge. I think it's high time to raise the issue again!

`readOGR`, from the [rgdal](http://robinlovelace.net/software/2013/11/26/installing-rgdal-on-ubuntu.html) package, cannot handle multipoint shapefiles, even though they load fine in [other GIS package](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55067/how-to-convert-multipoint-layer-to-point)s like QGIS. Of course, you can save the file as a single part object (see image below) in an external program, but ideally it would also be possible to do it in R.  Please see worked example below.

[image: multipart shp file in qgis]

```
download.file("http://www.personal.leeds.ac.uk/~georl/egs/lnd-stations-multi.zip", 
              "lnd-stations.zip") # download multi part polygon
unzip("lnd-stations.zip") # unzip
lndS <- readOGR(".", "lnd-stations", p4s = "+init=epsg:27700") # load

OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
Source: ".", layer: "lnd-stations"
with 2532 features and 27 fields
Feature type: wkbMultiPoint with 2 dimensions
Error in readOGR(".", "lnd-stations", p4s = "+init=epsg:27700") : 
  Incompatible geometry: 4
```

After performing "Multipart to singleparts" in the QGIS Vector menu (illustrated above) and saving the file, it loads fine in R. Try it:

```
download.file("http://www.personal.leeds.ac.uk/~georl/egs/lnd-stns.zip", 
              "lnd-stns.zip")
unzip("lnd-stns.zip")
lndS <- readOGR(".", "lnd-stns", p4s = "+init=epsg:27700")
plot(lndS)
```

Comment: I often read multipart shapefiles using readOGR. I do believe that there are certain types of geometries that ArcGIS creates that readOGR cannot handle. You could try maptools as an alternative.

Comment: Do you mean maptools readShapePoly? Please give it a try and let us know how you get on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be working with maptools. Loading the fixed shapefile as per your code:

```
download.file("http://www.personal.leeds.ac.uk/~georl/egs/lnd-stns.zip", "lnd-stns.zip")
unzip("lnd-stns.zip")
lndS.fix <- readOGR(".", "lnd-stns", p4s = "+init=epsg:27700")
plot(lndS.fix)

OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
Source: ".", layer: "lnd-stns"
with 2532 features and 27 fields
Feature type: wkbPoint with 2 dimensions
```

What does its size and structure look like?

```
str(lndS.fix)
Formal class 'SpatialPointsDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
  ..@ data       :'data.frame': 2532 obs. of  27 variables:
  .. ..$ CODE      : int [1:2532] 5520 5520 5520 5520 5520 5520 5520 5520 5520 5520 ...
<truncated>
```

Compare to the original multipoint data, but loaded with readShapePoint (which loads with no errors):

```
library(maptools)
download.file("http://www.personal.leeds.ac.uk/~georl/egs/lnd-stations-multi.zip", "lnd-stations.zip") # download multi part polygon
unzip("lnd-stations.zip") # unzip
lndS <- readShapePoints("lnd-stations.shp")

#Look at it
str(lndS)
Formal class 'SpatialPointsDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
  ..@ data       :'data.frame': 2532 obs. of  27 variables:
  .. ..$ CODE      : int [1:2532] 5520 5520 5520 5520 5520 5520 5520 5520 5520 5520 ...
<truncated>
```

Seems to have loaded OK - but are they really identical?

```
identical(lndS, lndS.fix)
FALSE
```

No ... but they have the same variables and the same set of XY coordinates:

```
identical(lndS@coordinates[[2]], lndS.fix@coordinates[[2]]
TRUE
```